# Error - Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to show one single record based on id. And I am getting this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Show function from ClientsController:

```
public function show( Clients $clients)
{
    $clients = Clients::find($clients->id);

    return view('clients.show', ['clients' => $clients]);

}
```

single show.blade view file

```
   @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
     <h1>{{ $clients->name }}</h1>


    @endsection
```

Clients model:

```
class Clients extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'type', 'user_id', 'sales_id', 'regions_id'
    ];
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function region(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Regions');
    }
    public function sales(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Sales');
    }
}
```

Database: https://take.ms/7kuo4

Comment: could you ```dd``` the clients variable and show us what you get?

Comment: Show your route declaration please

Comment: dd: Clients {#259 ▼
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: routes: Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('clients', 'ClientsController');


Route::resource('sales', 'SalesController');
Route::resource('regions', 'RegionsController');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');

Comment: please edit your question and add the routes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct your model binding using the singular for the type hinted variable name, i.e.:

```
public function show( Clients $client)
{
    return view('clients.show', ['clients' => $client]);
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The client for the client id that you're looking for is not being found.  It appears that the [route/model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) might not be configured correctly or you are [not receiving the proper id from the request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters).

If route/model binding were working correctly and if the passed in id were found then you shouldn't have to make the `find()` call.

```
$clients = Clients::find($clients->id);
```

The error in the blade template is because you are trying to access a property on a null value/a value that is not an object.

```
$clients->name
```

You can just use a null coalescing operator to handle the case if an object does not exist:

```
$clients->name ?? "No Name"
```

Comment: It's coming null, but why?

Comment: It's either your route model binding is off or you're not sending a valid ID for the client to the route.  You should be able to test using Postman: `GET /clients/<client_id>`.  Replace `<client_id>` with a valid client id from your database.  I would watch the whole series but here is a good video on it: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/3